# How to auto run the `M-x linum-mode` to display line number

Tags: emacs

I have installed the [package](http://web.student.tuwien.ac.at/~e0225855/linum/linum.html) to display line number in emacs.
However, each time I have to manually call `M-x linum-mode` to trigger this function.

Is there a way that I can modify my .emacs file and make it called automatically?

Thank you

```
; .emacs
(require 'linum)
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It should be sufficient to add

```
(global-linum-mode 1)
```

to your .emacs file.

Then linum-mode will start as soon as you open a file.

Answer (score 10):

I add `linum-on` to the hooks of various major modes I use. For example:

```
(add-hook 'sh-mode-hook #'linum-on)
```

That way I automatically get `linum-mode` in those modes and only those modes.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use **`M-x global-linum-mode`** to toggle the mode globally. I would prefer this version. I would turn it on only when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I am using spacemacs and none of the existing answers worked for me. However adding:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'linum
    (linum-mode))
```

in the `dotspacemacs/user-config` section worked. Someone can maybe point out why it works differently there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use load `linum-mode` automatically on specific buffer if needed. For example

`(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook 'linum-mode)`

This would automatically activate `linum-mode` on buffers derived from `prog-mode` (programming mode).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `use-package` example to load `linum-mode` for specific modes. In this case `clojure-mode`:

```
(use-package clojure-mode
:hook (clojure-mode . linum-mode))
```